# How to run multiple dataframes in a list through a block of code using for loops in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, rgdal, adehabitathr

I have a dataframe full of bird sightings, and I need to take that data and create .KMV files for each known, named bird territory (`territory.name`). I have a block of code that will take location data and create these .KMV files. By hand this involves creating a separate .CSV file for each of the named territories and running it individually through the block of code to produce the desired .KML files, but I want to automate the process using an R script.

I have made it so that each territory is in a separate dataframe using `split()`. Examples of these dataframes are below:

```
structure(list(season = c(" FA15", " FA15", " FA15", " FA15", 
" FA15"), year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), territory.name = c("Rocky", 
"Rocky", "Rocky", "Rocky", "Rocky"), plot = structure(c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Buena Vista", "Coches Prietos", 
"Coches Prietos ", "Field Station", "Field Station ", "Isthmus", 
"Navy", "Off-plot", "Offplot", "Portazuela", "Sauces", "Scorpion Ranch", 
"test"), class = "factor"), color.band = c("BKUAP", "BKUAP", 
"BKUAP", "BKUAP", "BKUAP"), lat = c(34.0117649920285, 34.0121079795063, 
34.011702965945, 34.0113220084459, 34.0113999601454), lon = c(-119.758454980329, 
-119.758648015559, -119.758594036102, -119.757832037285, -119.757832037285
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

and

```
structure(list(season = c(" FA15", " FA15", " FA15", " FA15", 
" FA15"), year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), territory.name = c("Hades", 
"Hades", "Hades", "Hades", "Hades"), plot = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Buena Vista", "Coches Prietos", "Coches Prietos ", 
"Field Station", "Field Station ", "Isthmus", "Navy", "Off-plot", 
"Offplot", "Portazuela", "Sauces", "Scorpion Ranch", "test"), class = "factor"), 
    color.band = c("PPOAY", "PPOAY", "PPOAY", "PPOAY", "PPOAY"
    ), lat = c(33.972684033215, 33.9726449735463, 33.9726769924164, 
    33.9730469696224, 33.9725800137967), lon = c(-119.723170017824, 
    -119.723048983142, -119.723543012515, -119.723651977256, 
    -119.723950959742)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ultimately there are 19 different dataframes in this list, one for each named territory. I think I need to use a for loop here, but have never done that before. Here's what I have so far from studying on Stack Overflow and reading documentation:

```
library(adehabitat)
library(rgdal)

df.list <- split(Fall2015_most, Fall2015_most$territory.name)

for(x in 1:length(df.list)){
  
###### Below is the code chunk for creating .KML files #####
# Remove rows with NA's in the lat and lon columns
x <- x[!is.na(x$lat) & !is.na(x$lon),]

# Ensure longitude is negative so it works in the western hemisphere 
x$lon <- x$lon*-

# Create a copy of the object to make into a SpatialPointsDataFrame
# Only include three columns (territory.name, x, and y coordinates) for estimating home ranges
# Make sure columns are listed  lon and lat
x.sp <- x[, c("territory.name", "lon", "lat")]

# Create a SpatialPointsDataFrame by defining the coordinates and long lat projection
coordinates(x.sp) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(x.sp) <-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
str(x.sp)

kernel.ref <- kernelUD(x.sp, h = "href")  # href = the reference bandwidth
image(kernel.ref) # plot
kernel.ref[[1]]@h # The smoothing factor is stored for each animal in the "h" slot
kernel.lscv <- kernelUD(x.sp, h = "LSCV") # Least square cross validation
image(kernel.lscv) # plot

par("mar")
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))

plotLSCV(kernel.lscv) # Look for a dip

x.kernel.poly <- getverticeshr(kernel.ref, percent = 70) 
print(x.kernel.poly)  # returns the area of each polygon

# Transform the point and MCP objects. 
x.spgeo <- spTransform(x.sp, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
x.bvkernalgeo <- spTransform(x.kernel.poly, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))

# Write data to a KML file that can be viewed in Google Earth
writeOGR(x.spgeo, "x.kml", layer="id", driver="KML", verbose=TRUE)
writeOGR(x.bvkernalgeo, "xBVkernel.kml", layer="id", driver="KML", verbose=TRUE)

} # close bracket for x
```

When I run this I get the error

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

in the line

```
for (x in 1:length(df.list))
```

How do I get the code to run for each of the dataframes. The filename I would use to run each territory manually through the code has been replaced by x's. My end goal is to successfully run each dataframe in `df.list` through the code successfully and automatically. Thanks!

Comment: `x` is a number. You cannot use brackets with a number. You need something like `dfx <-df.list[[x]]` to access the data frame in the list.

Comment: This looks wrong `x$lon*-`. Are you trying to create an arithmetic negative?

Comment: @IRTFM lon is longitude, I'm trying to ensure the longitude always comes out negative

Comment: My point was that whatever `lon` is will be immaterial. The expression `x$lon*-` is not going to be able to be parsed. It's not a complete R expression. You appear to think that a multiplication operator followed by a minus sign will give the multiplicative inverse of the object that precedes it. It won't. (Is your thought process perhaps distorted by the left-to-right examples in the dplyr/maggritr syntax? You could have simply placed a minus sign on the LHS of `x$lon` without the `*` operator. Probably better would be to use `abs`.)